# Shared folder doesn't appear in Linux guest VM - But in WinXP guest

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

A question for general understanding:
In VirtualBox Version 6.1.6 (on antiX Linux (based on debian)) shared folders for WinXP (as a Guest-VM) appearing in the Windows Network in the file manager without the need for installing any additional software.

Unlike in a Linux Guest VM, there is nothing, not even if I define a mount point /media/share for the folder in the VBox Properties of the regarding shared folder for the VM. Why?
How to fix it.?

Comment: Did you install guest additions in Linux guest? is the module `vboxsf` loaded (see with `lsmod`)? Have you tried to mount it manually (`mount -t vboxsf shared /mnt`)?

Comment: I din't install  guest additions yet as it was not necessary for Win-XP.
Obvisously for Linux VM's it is, will try.